# Eclipse got hung when opening junit test case

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

Today , When working with eclipse . My eclipse went to hung state whenever I open a junit test case file . On analyzed on that  .

Before Opening the File

```
  ~$ ps -o thcount 5458
  THCNT
   42
```

After Opening the File .

```
$ ps -o thcount 5458
THCNT
  195
```

I found sudden spike in threads usage .

I took thread dump using `jstack -l` for debugging this . I found most of the threads are in `BLOCKED` state .

Thread Dump :

Posting thread dump here makes my question become unreadable . Here is the threaddump https://docs.google.com/document/d/11nPbEkQMg-FMB9lPwvDK-ShNTygDN2biDUSPHMicdm4/edit?pli=1 .

Thank you ,
Kannan .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is your problem

Do you have a custom class loader? All the blocked threads are trying to load classes.

```
com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.junit.execution.core.UserDefinedClassLoader)
    at com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.junit.execution.core.UserDefinedClassLoader.loadClass(UserDefinedClassLoader.java:62)
    - locked <0x00000007efc97ea0> (a com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.junit.execution.core.UserDefinedClassLoader)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at com.zmedia.accounts.AccountsProto$ZAID$ZUID$UserTicket$ServiceTicket.initFields(AccountsProto.java:51314)
    at com.zmedia.accounts.AccountsProto$ZAID$ZUID$UserTicket$ServiceTicket.<clinit>(AccountsProto.java:52130)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at com.zmedia.resource.ResourceType.<init>(ResourceType.java:28)
    at com.zmedia.resource.ResourceType.loadResources(ResourceType.java:63)
    at com.zmedia.resource.URI.init(URI.java:859)
    at com.zmedia.resource.URI.<init>(URI.java:87)
    at com.zmedia.resource.URI.<init>(URI.java:81)
    at com.zmedia.accounts.Accounts$AccountURI.<init>(Accounts.java:13142)
    at com.zmedia.accounts.Accounts.getAccountURI(Accounts.java:13132)
    at com.zmedia.accounts.api.AccountTester.testGrandChildinSubresources(AccountTester.java:841)
```